# Firefox has wrong interpretation of em values

Tags: css, firefox

I am working on adaptive site, and have made everything in em values. Despite that, I have differences between Chrome and Firefox in interpreting `em`. Website is dev.morodeer.ru/stroymoidom; problem is with the metal bar with icons. On the width of about 670px everything in Chrome is great, but Mozilla cuts the right edge (as width of centered wrapper is set to 90%). Also, with same width of browsers, metal bar in Firefox is smaller, which leads me to a thought, that Mozilla counts smaller font-size.

Comment: em units belong with scams like "the check is in the mail".

Comment: In a 670 pixels wide browser window in Firefox, the page http://dev.morodeer.ru/stroymoidom has no visible navigation bar, i.e. the element with `id="buttons_under_logo"` just doesn’t appear at all. So there’s a problem in the overall design, probably not that much related to the units used.

Comment: We can't reproduce this without code in the question, and also browsers don't "interpret em wrong".

Answer (score 0):

> The em and ex units depend on the font and may be different for each element in the document.

quoted from: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

maybe you use default fonts and firefox uses a different one as e.g. chrome does?

i'd suggest you to use px or % values instead of em for block-layout size values.

use em for font sizes, 1em = font size of the browser, 2em = 2* font size of the browser, 0.5 em = 0.5*font size of the browser .. and so on ;)

If you already knew that part: yes, firefox and chrome can have different font-sizes and em might influent your font size in a different way then.